# Write a list of Julia DataFrames to file

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a list of Julia DataFrames that I want to write to file. What is the fastest way to write these out? I'm looking for something akin to rds files in R.

Comment: [JLD](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl) [JLD2](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl) [BSON](https://github.com/MikeInnes/BSON.jl)

Answer (score 0):

I routinely use `serialize` and `deserialize` from the `Serialization` module. Note that this is Julia-version specific, but apart from that this is the most robust approach currently.

You can also consider https://github.com/JuliaData/Feather.jl, but it does not support all possible data types that you can store in a `DataFrame` (but covers all standard types).

Here https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/04_loadsave.ipynb you can find some benchmarks (at the end of the notebook).

Answer (score 0):

[JLD2](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl) solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Note that JLD2 currently has a problem with properly handling of `Missing` values, see e.g. https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl/issues/131. So caution is needed till this gets fixed.